# How do i check if a string has a number in it

Tags: javascript

For example:

```
var variable = `2`
if (variable == {insert checker}) {
  console.log(`string`)
}
```

I want to know if there is something that would check if my variable is a number or not.
I need it so that i can check if the variable is formatted properly.
If something like this doesn't exist a function that checks if a number is a number would also be nice to have.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) Have you tried anything yet? Could [`isNaN(variable)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) be useful?

Answer (score 3):

```
 if(isNumeric(val)) { alert('number'); } 
else { alert('not number'); }


function isNumeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Comment: am i able to replace parseFloat with the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators)

Comment: ```var x = `1`

var isNumeric = function (n) {
    return !isNaN(+n) && isFinite(n);
}

console.log(isNumeric(x));```

Comment: https://medium.com/@nikjohn/cast-to-number-in-javascript-using-the-unary-operator-f4ca67c792ce    go through this it will help you

Comment: +false  // 0
+‘123’  // 123
+0xBABE // 47806 (Hexadecimal)
+null   // 0   .........  + will retrun true when you pass null
+function(val) {return val } // NaN

Answer (score 2):

`isNaN` return `is not a number`. You can verify by this javascript function.

```js
console.log(!isNaN(111));
console.log(!isNaN("111"));
console.log(!isNaN("11asd"));
```

Comment: im worried about using this since to me it looks like it relies on js to use the string of a number as a number which is usually not a stable way of doing things. It does work however

Answer (score 1):

You can use the match method with a regexp, /\d/ means any digit, or the same as: /[0-9]/

```js
var variable = '1'
if (variable.match(/\d/)) {
  console.log('number');
} else{
  console.log('not a number');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, this regex should do the job.
/\d/ is basically the same as /[0-9]/

```js
function hasNumber(string) {
  return /\d/.test(string);
}
```

Comment: Is /\d/ commonly used and should i learn what things that are written like that mean?